# Login into aws connect using awssdk for php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I need to auto login into Amazon connect instance using PHP awssdk . The AWS sdk is included in the project and is being used to connect to S3 buckets for storing and retrieving the files. But my requirement is to login the user as an agent into Amazon connect when he logs into the web app. The user has already been created in Amazon connect. Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log agents into Connect you need to use the Streams API found here.

https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams

The Connect API itself doesn't support agent login etc.